# data source in InfoPath is very slow

Tags: 2013, infopath

i have created InfoPath form with SQL Server data source but the form load very slow "the data source get more than 1000 items".

Is there is any way to fast the performance?

Comment: How much time it takes to load the form? Where you are populating the 1000 items at once?

Comment: about  5 second to 20

Comment: 5 Secs seems normal time frame but 20 isn't. Are you populating these 1000 items in a dropdown? It would be great if you add more details and the scenario in your question.

Comment: SharePoint API is notoriously slow, so 20 seconds is not uncommon. You are communicating to SharePoint and then SharePoint has to fetch the data from another place. Start by ruling out the SQL server, run the same query but without SharePoint as proxy